# Table data issue

Tags: python, html, css

I am using html in python but the data is long in some cells and they come in front of next cell. 
I am using following code for table:

```
packages_table = TABLE(_border=1,_width="100%",_font=12)
            packages_table.append(TR(
            TH("Transaction ID",_width="17%",_align="LEFT"),
            TH("Date",_width="17%",_align="LEFT"),
            TH("Time",_width="10%",_align="LEFT"),
            TH("Package",_width="30%",_align="LEFT"),
            TH("Amount(EUR) ("+currency1+")",_width="24%",_align="LEFT")
            ))
```

and I am populating using this

```
packages_table.append(TR(str(tx_id),str(date),str(time),str(receiver),str(amount)))
```

Sample Output

[image]

Comment: `TABLE` is not built-in Python class. So what lib are you using?

Comment: What solution are you looking for? Fix in HTML directly, or from within the `packages_table` instance?

Comment: In this case I believe you can fix this with css.

Comment: You can use jinja2 to create this templates.

Comment: I am using HTMLMixin, Template, FDP. I am printing this on pdf